# XMPP client that respects System Certificate Stores

Tags: windows, xmpp

We have an internal CA certificate we are using to sign the SSL/TLS certificate for our OpenFire XMPP server internally.

However, we can't seem to find an XMPP client willing to respect the internal CA certificate inside the system's trusted certificate authority stores.

Is there an XMPP client for Windows which inherits the CA trust store on the system and *doesn't* require its own certificate store to contain the CA cert in order to trust the cert?